# How to make text wrap round fixed div

Tags: css-float

There is a really simple solution to this I'm sure, but I can't find it.

I want some body text to wrap around two divs - an infobox at the top left, and a pullquote on the right 25% of the way down.

```
    <div class="A">

    <div class="B">
    Infobox
    </div>

    <div class="D">  
    Lorem ipsum...
    </div>

   <div class="C">
   Pullquote
   </div>

   </div>
```

I have no problem getting it to wrap around the infobox, but the pullquote gets pushed to the bottom. I can fix its position but then the text runs behind it.

This is my CSS

```
   .A {
   height: 100em;
   width:100%;
   background-color: red;
   }

   .B {
   height: 2em;
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
   background-color: blue;
   }

   .C {
   height: 2em;
   width: 20%;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   background-color: green;
   }

   .D {

   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are having problems putting the pull quote on the top right, 25% down. If you want the Lorem ipsum on the right hand side of your info box then do this

```
.A {
    border-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.B {
    height: 2em;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}

.C {
    height: 2em;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

.D {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ShEsKo but that still meets the problem I encountered, which is that the Lorem Ipsum in D still runs behind div C. In the end, after doing more research, I've concluded that this perhaps isn't possible with css after all.

Comment: Nothing is impossible my friend :P
If you could attach an image of the design you're looking for I could help you out. I'm just not sure what you're trying to do.